# Image Collection Statistics in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, ndvi, statistics

How can I extarct mean of each image collection in google earth engine?
for example for this code:

```js
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2001-01-01")
.select("NDVI");

print(modis)

var mod13 = modis.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});
```

Comment: Do you want the pixel-wise mean for each pixel or the mean per image/scene?

Comment: I'm going to extract mean of each image which is called with image collection(mean per image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earth Engine provides very nice functionality to calculate statistics on imagery called [reducers](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_intro). There are plenty of ways to use reducers but as simple examples you can calculate the statistics at the pixel level or provide a geometry to calculate statistics:

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2001-01-01")
.select("NDVI");

print(modis)

var mod13 = modis.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

// calculate the mean of value for each pixel
var meanMod13 = mod13.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
Map.addLayer(meanMod13,{min:0,max:1},'Mean NDVI')

// calculate the mean value for a region
var geom = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-88,34,-87,35])
Map.addLayer(geom)
// *Note that reduceRegion works only on ee.Image not ee.ImageCollection data types
var zonalStats = meanMod13.reduceRegion({
    geometry: geom,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 1000,
    bestEffort: true
});
print(zonalStats)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How could I use the mean per region for all images of an ImageCollection? So it automatically does it  and gives me the results in a list. With a function?

Comment: Yes, you can create a function that takes an image as input, applies the reduction and outputs the statistics as a feature so the output will be a feature collection. The function will need to be mapped over the image collection and you can get the list of values out of the feature collection.